# Dealing with square brackets in regex

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe

I have some data, which looks like this:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    'col' = c(
      'some words [remove this] more words',
      'some other words [I want this gone] this is fine',
      '[nope.  get rid of it] but keep this',
      'all of this is fine',
      '[but] this [should] go [away]')
    )

                                               col
1              some words [remove this] more words
2 some other words [I want this gone] this is fine
3              [nope  get rid of it] but keep this
4                              all of this is fine
5                    [but] this [should] go [away]
```

I want to remove all of the square brackets and everything in between them.

```
goal_df <- df <-
  data.frame(
    'col' = c(
      'some words more words',
      'some other words this is fine',
      'but keep this',
      'all of this is fine',
      'this go')
  )

                            col
1         some words more words
2 some other words this is fine
3                 but keep this
4           all of this is fine
5                       this go
```

I thought that using regex (which is my worst skill in programming) would be the solution, but I can't seem to get that to work. I'm using `df$col <- gsub( "[.*?]", "", df$col)` but that doesn't make any changes.

Answer (score 3):

We may match the `[`, followed by one or more characters that are not `]` followed by `]` and any space as pattern and replace with blank (`""`) in `gsub`.  The `[]` are metacharacters so escape (`\\`)

```
df$col <- trimws(gsub("\\[[^]]+\\]\\s?", "", df$col))
```

-output

```
> df
                            col
1         some words more words
2 some other words this is fine
3                 but keep this
4           all of this is fine
5                       this go
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can you explain what the s? at the end does?  I'm terrible at regex, so I apologize if that's a dumb question.

Comment: @pkpto39 If i use `\\s`, it will not match the last one as there is no space after that `]`.  You may either use `\\s*`. - zero or more space or `?`  that does the zero or more matching

Comment: `trimws` is a good idea, and if I were you I would exploit it to the fullest (M$ trad), adding all eventual whitespaces on each side in the pattern, to "normalize" them in a single space: `trimws(gsub("\\s*\\[[^]]+\\]\\s*", " ", df$col))`

Answer (score 1):

A slightly easier-to-parse solution is with quantifier `*` made non-greeedy by `?`:

```
gsub("\\s?\\[.*?\\]+", "", df$col)
[1] "some words more words"         "some other words this is fine" " but keep this"               
[4] "all of this is fine"           " this go"
```

To remove leading or trailing white space use `trimws`